# Do the degrees of the vertices of a tree determine it's structure?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

Suppose I give you $n$ vertices, I tell you that these vertices are connected by edges to form a tree, and I tell you that the degree of the vertices are $d_1,\ldots,d_n$.

Does that determine the tree (i.e., the edges of the tree) uniquely?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No it does not. Consider two trees each with $7$ vertices and degrees $1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3$.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure it matters, but I intend the tree to be labelled. So points $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ are given (i.e., fixed in space) and the degree $d_i$ of each vertex is given. Does it matter?

Comment: Do you mean to say that the degree of vertices with same label in both trees are to be equal?

Comment: Well, I think having the degree of vertices with same label in both trees equal can be accomplished with relabelling. Here is another way to think about it. Start with a tree. Label the vertices. Record the degrees of the vertices. Now delete all edges. Keep the labels the same. Can you recover the edges using just the record of the degrees?

Comment: I don't think so. Consider the first tree with vertices labelled as $a, b, c, d, e, f, g$ in obvious manner with degrees $3, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1$. After deleting the edges as you say, what is to prevent one from saying that $bf$ and $ce$ formed an edge instead of $be$ and $cf$?

Comment: I agree. Thanks.